# chart.js cuts data points to half

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart showing website calls the last 7 days. There it is:
[image: chart]
Here is the initialization:

```
varwebsitecalls_chart = new Chart(websitecalls_chartel, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Sa", "So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Websitecalls',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: '#00000',
            backgroundColor: '#ffff',
            pointStyle: 'circle',
            pointRadius: 7,
            cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
            tension: 0.4,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                grid: {
                    display: false,
                }
            },
            y: {
                min: 0,
                ticks: {
                    precision: 0,
                    font: {
                        family: 'Montserrat',
                    },
                },
                grid: {
                    borderDash: [5, 5],
                }
            },
        }
    },
});
```

**Problem:**
The Problem is that the chart cuts of the circles when the data is 0 because I set min to 0. I have to set min to 0 because negative websitecalls can not exist. If I do not set it -1 will be displayed. Is there a way to fix this designtechnical issue?

Thanks in advance,
Filip.

Comment: Hello. Could you also add an example set of dummy data (data_week.data) ?

Comment: @AntiqTech I added example data. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why, but defining `y.beginAtZero: true` instead of `y.min: 0` will solve the problem.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('websitecalls_chartel', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Sa", "So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Websitecalls',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#00000',
      backgroundColor: '#ffff',
      pointStyle: 'circle',
      pointRadius: 7,
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
      tension: 0.4,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          precision: 0,
          font: {
            family: 'Montserrat',
          },
        },
        grid: {
          borderDash: [5, 5],
        }
      },
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="websitecalls_chartel" height="80"></canvas>
```

[Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) states...

- `beginAtZero`: if `true`, scale will include 0 if it is not already included.
- `min`: user defined minimum number for the scale, overrides minimum value from data.

Comment: Design filosophy of chart.js if I remember correctly from an issue putted in about this. min: value says we dont want to see anything below that value so points and things also get cut off.

Comment: This is weird. I'm trying your code on w3schools and it is not working.  It's frustrating.   Maybe there is an issue regarding chart.js version   https://www.w3schools.com/ai/tryit.asp?filename=tryai_chartjs_scatter

Comment: Yeah, I checked again. they were using 2.9.4.  you're using 3.7.1.